# Shortest Path in a 2d matrix to reach (m,n) from 0,0 considering all possible directions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have read the problems to reach to (m,n) in a 2D matrix using DP where we can only move rightwards or diagonally.
In this problem for every cell (i,j), I will only check (i-1,j) and (i,j-1) and add the minimum to the path.This will be the shortest path to reach (i,j).

What if I can move in any possible direction? Will the same approach be able to solve this problem or it will get stuck in an infinite loop?
Thanks

Comment: In that case use a proper shortest path algorithm like breadth-first-search (0/1 weights), Dijkstra (weights >= 0) or Bellman-Ford (arbitrary weights). Although if you just have a regular grid without obstacles or edge weights, you will always have to go m + n steps

Comment: dp only works if the graph is dag. When you can go in all the directions then it has circles.

Comment: @hege_hegedus the correct term is 'cycles'

Comment: @javadba thanks, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use the same approach, except for one minor change: Since now all directions are allowed, you'll need to keep a record of fields you've already visited, in order to prevent an infinite-loop - like for example moving left-right-left-right-... .

Comment: So in which order do you compute the values f(i,j) then? I think there is a lot missing from this answer, because essentially you need to get to breadth-first order somehow (or even shortest distance order in the general case)

Comment: @NiklasB. the order doesn't exactly matter. Clock-wise or ordered by weight, just whatever you prefer

Comment: Actually order is all that matters here. It's what differentiate all the label-setting search algorithms from each other (i.e. depth-first vs breadth-first vs Dijkstra vs A*, ...)

Comment: @NiklasB. ops approach uses the rather naive approach of selecting the smallest element in the matrix as next element. So, well... guess that's what you meant. I think i misunderstood your question

Comment: Ok let's put it differently. Say we don't have a "trivial" grid where the answer f(i,j) is just i + j. For example because there are obstacles in the grid. Now you're proposing to use the same label-setting approach as OP, which is fine. But the order is important: Say the field (i,j) is only accessible from the "south". We then need to compute f(i+1, j) before we compute f(i,j), but we can't determine the order by a simple "on-demand" approach to resolve dependencies like we can usually do with DP in the case where the states form a DAG.

Comment: The "correct" approach here is to process the states in breadth-first order (in the case with only 0/1 weights) or even to use the Dijkstra ordering. In particular, clock-wise or row-by-row or other static orders can not work because of the case I mentioned above.

Comment: @Paul  DP works on gradually building up sub-problems. How is that the case here? The shortest path from a point in Row2 may depend on Row5. So then this does not appear to be DP but instead backtracking / DFS - along the lines off what Niklas is saying.

Comment: @Paul: I can keep track of visited cell but will that guarantee me shortest path?